# Rails :remote => true operating on document object?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got the following `index.js.erb`:

```
$(function () {
  var $team = $('#createTeam'),
      $user = $('#createUser'),
      $userPanel = $('.createUserPanel'),
      $teamPanel = $('.createTeamPanel');

  $user.click(function(){
    $userPanel.append('<%= j render 'form_user' %>').fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });

  $team.click(function(){
    $teamPanel.append('<%= j render 'form_team' %>').fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
})();
```

To go along with these links in my `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to "+", "#", 'data-action' =>"create",'data-target'=> "team", id: "createTeam", remote: true %>

<%= link_to "+", "#", 'data-action' =>"create",'data-target'=> "user", id: "createUser", remote: true %>
```

When I click on either of the links the first time, nothing happens, but on the successive 2nd and 3rd clicks both forms appears. After each click of the link the button should fade out and the form should appear in a separate div.

The desired implementation is when *either* link is clicked the `form_*` will appear, and the button will fade out. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling javascript that's then loaded and binding events to your elements. That's why the 2nd click works -- the click event is bound after the first click which "calls" the javascript to come be loaded.

It looks like you don't need anything dynamic from your AJAX call. You can remove the "remote: true" option from the link_to helper and simply place the contents of index.js.erb in your index.html.erb (probably at the bottom or in the :script content block)

I usually don't end up using the remote helper stuff, but, think of it like an AJAX call, you want to make a request to an action, have it processed, and return some kind of information about what happened

Answer (score 1):

So what is happening here is the following:

You click one of the links which sends a request to the #index controller action.  This returns you index.js.erb.

The first time you return this, nothing happens because the JS has just been loaded, so as far as JS is concerned nothing has happened yet.  You need to add something to `index.js.erb` that will call the append action when the JS is initially loaded.

As to both forms appearing at once, you may have to be more specific about what you want to append to.  You seem to be selecting both classes when you call append.  Perhaps you could include more of the `index.html.erb` in your question.

Comment: thanks for the insight but "add something" to what? The idea is a user clicks the link and the form is rendered on the page. Are you suggesting wrapping the $foo.append(); in a method like $.ready inside of the click callback function?